# How to convert a BeautifulSoup tag to JSON?

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

I have a type element, `bs4.element.Tag`, product of a web scraping, I usually do: `json.loads (soup.find ('script', type = 'application / ld + json'). Text)` , but on this page it only appears in: `<script> </script>` so I had to do: `scripts = soup.find_all ('script')` until I get to the one that interests me: `script = scripts [18]`.

The variable in question is `script`. My problem is that I want to access its attributes, for example `script ['goodsInfo']`, obviously being an element type `bs4.element.Tag`, try to do: `script.attrs` and return me `{}`. Then I tried to convert it to the type `json: json.loads (str (script))` and it throws me the *exception: 'JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)'*

This is my code:

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url_aux = 'https://www.shein.com/Mock-neck-Brush-Stroke-Print-Bodycon-Dress-p-941649-cat-1727.html?scici=navbar_2~~tab01navbar04~~4~~real_1727~~~~0~~0'

response = requests.get(url_aux)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

scripts = soup.find_all('script')
script = scripts[18]

print(json.loads(str(script)))
#output: JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

print(type(script))
#output: bs4.element.Tag

print(str(json.loads(str(script))))
```

Comment: Is there always the same structure after the `var gbProductDetailsSsrData`?
Because you could use `re` package in this case to retrieve the data.

Comment: you need to find the first `{` and last `}` plus `1`. then replacing `whitespace` and `\n` with blank `""` then you can start to load !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `json` module to extract the data, but first it's necessary to locate the right info - you can use `re` module for that.

For example:

```
import re
import json
import requests

url = 'https://eur.shein.com/Mock-neck-Brush-Stroke-Print-Bodycon-Dress-p-941649-cat-1727.html?scici=navbar_2~~tab01navbar04~~4~~real_1727~~~~0~~0&ref=www&rep=dir&ret=eur'

txt = re.findall(r'goodsInfo\s*:\s*({.*})', requests.get(url).text)[0]

data = json.loads(txt)

# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4)) # <-- uncomment to see all data

print(data['detail']['goods_name'])
print(data['detail']['brand'])
print('Num of comments:', data['detail']['comment']['comment_num'])
```

Prints:

```
Mock-neck Brush Stroke Print Bodycon Dress
SHEIN
Num of comments: 17
```

Comment: Thank you for the regex. It's nice to have one to get any object in any script. Well played !

Answer (score 0):

BS4 does not parse javascript, from BS4's `Tag` object's POV the text in a `<script>` tag is, well, just text. I don't have any idea what this script looks like (since you didn't post it and I'm not going to bother try and find it), but if your expectations were that `script ['goodsInfo']` would return the value of a JS variables named 'goodInfo' then, bad news, it's not going to work that way.

Also, Javascript is not JSON, so the chances a JS snippet will be valid json are rather small to say the least. The proper syntax to test it would be quite simply the same as the one you used for you first use case, ie `json.loads(script.text)`, but I assume that's the first thing you tried ;-)

So, well, I'm afraid you'll have to manually parse this script to extract the relevant part. Depending on what the js code looks like, it may be a matter of a few lines of basic string parsing / regexp stuff, or it may require a proper Javascript parser etc.

Comment: I have tried to publish the output but it exceeds the allowed characters